# How i can write this query in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I need help for this query in laravel

```php
$forums = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM forums 
                      WHERE category = '.$f.' && 
                      (community = "'.$c.'" || community = "xx") 
                      ORDER BY id ASC');
```

But how i can write this with laravel sytaxt?
`$forums = Forums::where()`

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel is assuming that the database table is the plural form of the model name.
I think your Model is `Forum` not `Forums`.

Try this :

```
$forums = Forum::where("category", $f)
   ->where(function($query) use($c) {
         $query->where("community", $c)
              ->orWhere("community", "xx");
          })
   ->orderBy("id", "ASC")
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$forums = Forum::where("category", $f)
    ->where(function($query) use($c) {
         $query->where("community", $c)
              ->orWhere("community", "xx");
          })
    ->orderBy("id", "ASC")
    ->get();
```